# How could Hal fire his own boss in "Company Picnic"?

Tags: plot-explanation, malcolm-in-the-middle

In the *Malcolm in the Middle* episode "Company Picnic", Hal was nervous to meet his new boss at the company picnic, but when they met everything went well. Surprisingly, the new boss called him a different name and then after a while, Hal told him he is fired... I'm lost at this point. What happened? How could Hal fire his own boss?

Comment: I haven't seen the episode in a long time, but if I remember correctly, Hal's new boss was under the impression that Hal was in fact *his* boss, which is why he was calling him the wrong name. Hal was too embarrassed to simply point out that his new boss was wrong, so instead he tried to get out of the situation by firing his own boss.

Comment: ooh .. I see .. thus, this explains why Lois told him he should go and make things right with the new boss .. but still, at some earlier scene the new boss introduced him to give a little speech to his colleagues, seemed like he knows already that he is his new supervisor ..  hmmm ..

Answer (score 3):

As Dr R Dizzle correctly said, Hal's new boss was under the impression that Hal was his boss. After panicking and firing him, the new guy decided to quit because he didn't want to work for a guy like that